# Mining a text file for specific keywords

Tags: text-files, counting, keyword-search

I have a 15MB file in .txt; I want to specify four to five keywords to see how many times they appeared in the file and then plot them in histogram like manner. Please suggest a way out

Comment: Try writing code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, if you are looking for occurences of wordOne, wordTwo, or wordThree, you can do something like this:

```
cat myFile | egrep -o "wordOne|wordTwo|wordThree" | sort | uniq -c
```

This means: Read myFile, look for occurences of wordOne, wordTwo, and wordThree and output only those occurences, sort the lines of the output, remove duplicates while counting number of occurences.

Note here that this will match wordOneOther as well because we are not ensuring word boundaries. That can be done in several ways but depends on what you need and what your file looks like.

Plotting is a whole other question. You could either use something like gnuplot or you can paste the output to excel or matlab or something...

Answer (score 0):

Install nltk. Will be very useful to do text analysis. Once you have installed it, the following code will help you to get word count of a specific word:

```
import nltk

with open('C:\\demo.txt', 'r') as f:
    #The following line will create a list of words from the text.
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(f.read())
    #print (words)
    #The following line will create a word-frequency combo, so you can call any word to get its frequency
    fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
    print (fdist['This'])
```

Once you have this data ready and stored in a format of your choice, you can use matplotlib or seaborn to create a simple histogram.

Comment: Sorry, I was checking Python questions and found yours. Didn't realise you hadn't mentioned python at all!

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the code in 'spider', but it was throwing this error <_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:\\output.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>. I guess the code doesn't fetch the file

Comment: Hi. Could you please show the complete error?
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:\\output.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'> doesnt look like an error. It looks like you tried to print the object f in the line:
"with open('C:\\demo.txt', 'r') as f:"
and python printed the object